# Parsing csv file in scala

Tags: scala

How can i parse this csv file in Scala, to extract an object Data contain (date,time,longitude,latitude)

*M…….:Dy4.5

*N……….:14_540

*V…..:N

*S….:1.2.1

*yyyy/mm/dd;hh:mm:ss;long;lat

2016/05/09;12:50:19;-122.45006;38.47320

2016/05/09;13:04:10;-122.45011;38.47317

i already wrote this function but it just read the file, i don't know how to transform it into object

```
def readData(fileName:String): Vector[Array[String]] = {
      for {
        line <- Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().toVector
        values = line.split(";").map(_.trim)
      } yield values
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to define 'values' as a variable or value. You can use a regular expression to find and save particular segments of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scala type matching for this to build up on Anastasiia Kharchenko's response

```
def readData(fileName:String): Vector[Data] = {
  for {
    line <- Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().toVector
    data <- parseCsvLine(line)
  } yield data
}

def parseCsvLine(line: String): Option[Data] = {
    line.split(";").toVector.map(_.trim) match {
             case Vector(date, time, longitude, latitude) => Some(Data(date, time, longitude, latitude))
             case _ => println(s"WARNING UNKNOWN DATA FORMAT FOR LINE: $line")
                       None
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: your solution work perfectly, thanks
Can you please help me to convert date from String to a type Date. i tried that, but I got always a NullPointerException:
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
Some(Data(format.parse(date),....

Comment: So first I would make sure everything was parsed correctly, then I would have something in the case class for the data (if we continue with the example above) `case class Data(date: String, time: String, longitude: String, latitude: String) { def getDate(): java.util.Date = { val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); format.parse(date) } }` I would not change the date in the parseCsv function as the function should only focus on parsing a csv line

Comment: i have used java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter and it resolve my issue, because it's not practical to redefine getter for each attribute, Thank a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have class Data

```
case class Data(date: String, time: String, longitude: String, latitude: String)
```

(date and time are strings just for simplifying example).

The code below will give you a vector of Data objects

```
def readData(fileName:String): Vector[Data] = {
  for {
    line <- Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().toVector
    values = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
    date = Date(values(0), values(1), values(2), values(3))
  } yield date
}
```

Comment: When I try your solution I go the error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1